# Node.js : Run the function in background

Tags: javascript, node.js

I Need to run the function in Background

```
function bk () {
    console.log("Function Start");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
        y = 0
    }
    console.log("Function END");
}

console.log("MAIN START");
bk()
console.log("MAIN end");
```

at present the output is :

```
MAIN START
Function Start
Function END
MAIN end
```

Desired output is :

```
MAIN START
MAIN end
Function Start
Function END
```

OR

```
MAIN START
Function Start
MAIN end
Function END
```

Idea is that the JS should not wait for Function to end to print "MAIN END"

Comment: There is no such thing as "background". Node.js is single threaded and uses an event loop. Once this function is called, no other function can run in "foreground" in the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:-

```
console.log("MAIN START");
setTimeout(bk,0);
console.log("MAIN end");
```

Comment: It can be and I think someone already mentioned it. But if it's a task you want to achieve in parallel to something else, I guess it would be better you handle this function in a separate service altogether. And use Promise to resolve the output of that service call.

Comment: Lakshya : 
setTimeout(bk(),0); is giving error.
Where as "setTimeout(bk,0);" runs fine.
How do I pass the arguments to the function

Comment: You can do setTimeout(bk,0,a,b). Make sure bk accepts a and b in its function definition. You could also do setTimeout(()=>bk(a,b),0) or setTimeout(bk.bind(null,a,b),0);

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't exactly mean calling it in the background but deferring it, to achieve this you could use `Promise.resolve().then(bk)`.

Comment: In case BK function needs arguments, Which is the case in real.
If I use Promise.resolve().then(bk), It work as desired. But if I use Promise.resolve().then(bk()), then it does not.

Comment: Promise.resolve().then(bk, "a", "b") Works, where a and b are arguments

Comment: You could use an arrow function: `Promise.resolve().then(() => bk('a', 'b'))`.

Answer (score 1):

One option

```
let bk = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

        resolve(() => {
            console.log("Function Start");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                y = 0
            }
            console.log("Function END");
        });
    })


console.log("MAIN START");
bk.then( e => e())
console.log("MAIN end");
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js has single threaded architecture, but you can detach work from event loop because of operations which would otherwise block whole eventloop (fileread, request etc.). In case you dont have any asynchronous operation by hand, like file reading, reqest etc. you can use set timeout to simulate that operation:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function bkwork() {
    console.log("Function Start");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        y = 0;
        await sleep(1000)
    }
    console.log("Function END");
}

console.log("MAIN START");
bkwork();
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log("Hola");
}
```

In the output you can see that "hola" loop is processed sooner then function ends. Hope this help someway :)

EDIT!
Answer provided by [maxi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12458604/maxi) is even better to use.